# Output smaller chunks to stdout in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using FFmpeg to stream raw PCM data from an internet radio stream, which I then run through some processing.
FFmpeg buffers around 10 seconds before sending any output to stdout, and I've been trying to get it to send data in more frequent intervals, so I can process it in smaller chunks.

I've looked at various FFmpeg command line options, but could not find one that will decrease the internal buffering used.
Looking at [the various format options](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html), I've tried `-fflags nobuffer` and `-avioflags direct` on both input and output, to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: Full command please.

Comment: As I said, I tried various combinations of `nobuffer` and `direct`, but my basic command is pretty simple:

`ffmpeg -i http://example.com/stream.m3u8 -ar 16000 -f s16_le -`